# Does space expansion change value when traveling near the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, dark-energy

To draw an analogy, we receive roughly the same amount of cosmic background radiation from all directions. However if we were to travel near the speed of light relative to the reference frame where that is true we would observe the cosmic background radiation to be blue shifted in front of us as we travel.

Similarly, we believe that space is expanding roughly uniformly in all directions. If you were to travel near the speed of light would the rate of expansion in front of you be shifted to a different rate?

For example, one of the most energetic cosmic rays ever detected was a proton which could travel across the Milky Way galaxy in 5 minutes in its own frame. Our galaxy is about 100,000 light years across. If we were traveling at this same rate relative to our galaxy, would we observe 100,000 years worth of space expansion in 5 minutes?

Comment: I don't see why you mention dark energy in the title. Dark energy does change the expansion rate, but so does dark matter, ordinary matter and radiation. It's a good question about the expansion rate as observed by a non-comoving observer, but it has nothing specifically to do with dark energy.

Comment: @JohnRennie I think I understand your point. I'll change "Dark Energy" to "space expansion".